# Onclick location specifics

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some help with JAVASCRIPT/CSS/HTML. I have created a small dialog for forms, like so:

```
#greyout{
background-image:url('../res/greyout.png');
display:none;
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
z-index:10;
}
.forms{

width:20%;
position:absolute;
top:20%;
left:40%;
right:40%;
display:none;
height:30%;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color:white;
color:black;
text-align:center;
}
```

The form divs are within the greyout div in the HTML. Moreover, I have a button that triggers this function:

```
function login()
{
    document.getElementById("greyout").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("loginForm").style.display="block";
}
function signup()
{
    document.getElementById("greyout").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("signupForm").style.display="block";
}
```

I want to make sure that when I press the greyed out background, the dialog classed "forms" will disappear so as the greyout of the page. Trying to make an onclick event for the greyout div made it so pressing even on the dialog itself, it will trigger. I need to listen only when the user has pressed in the background. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use onclick="signup();" AND onclick="login();" where they are needed on the divs/buttons/tags @user3312767

Comment: @user3312767 I don't think you understood. I can make it appear I just can't make it go away. I want to press on the greyed out background and it will go back to normal, but NOT when I press the dialog itself.

Comment: @user3312767 I still can't make this work: http://jsbin.com/wuramanuxi/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected as the event bubbles up the DOM tree. Try to listen to onclick on the outer and inner div, if the inner one is clicked just return false to cancel the event bubbling and keep you current listener for the outer div.

Comment: I tried doing this: http://jsbin.com/wuramanuxi/1/edit?js,output. Mind elaborating how we can get this working with an example without the use of jquery?

Comment: I got it working, but it is not nice. I hope it illustrates that both onclick listeners get called. For some reason the return false did not do the trick but I think the more elegant way is to attach the event not via html but JS and to properly cancel it.

Comment: I haven't found working examples on this. I might want to ask a question on this myself.